# ArrayList of String Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I would like to do something like this:

```
private ArrayList<String[]> addresses = new ArrayList<String[3]>();
```

This does not seem to work. Whats the easiest way of storing multiple addresses with 3 fields per address in an array without creating a separate class for it?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use a second ArrayList for the 3 strings, not a primitive array. Ie.
`private List<List<String>> addresses = new ArrayList<List<String>>();`

Then you can have:

```
ArrayList<String> singleAddress = new ArrayList<String>();
singleAddress.add("17 Fake Street");
singleAddress.add("Phoney town");
singleAddress.add("Makebelieveland");

addresses.add(singleAddress);
```

(I think some strange things can happen with type erasure here, but I don't think it should matter here)

If you're dead set on using a primitive array, only a minor change is required to get your example to work. As explained in other answers, the size of the array can not be included in the declaration. So changing:

```
private ArrayList<String[]> addresses = new ArrayList<String[3]>();
```

to

```
private ArrayList<String[]> addresses = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

will work.

Answer (score 23):

```
List<String[]> addresses = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String[] addressesArr  = new String[3];

addressesArr[0] = "zero";
addressesArr[1] = "one";
addressesArr[2] = "two";

addresses.add(addressesArr);
```

Answer (score 10):

I wouldn't use arrays. They're problematic for several reasons and you can't declare it in terms of a specific array size anyway. Try:

```
List<List<String>> addresses = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

But honestly for addresses, I'd create a class to model them.

If you were to use arrays it would be:

```
List<String[]> addresses = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

ie you can't declare the size of the array.

Lastly, don't declare your types as concrete types in instances like this (ie for `addresses`). Use the interface as I've done above. This applies to member variables, return types and parameter types.

Answer (score 7):

Simple and straight forward way to create ArrayList of String

```
    List<String> category = Arrays.asList("everton", "liverpool", "swansea", "chelsea");
```

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

You can't force the String arrays to have a specific size.
You can do this:

```
private List<String[]> addresses = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

but an array of any size can be added to this list.

However, as others have mentioned, the correct thing to do here is to create a separate class representing addresses. Then you would have something like:

```
private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private List<String[]> addresses = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

this will work defenitely...

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> PriceModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> PriceQtyList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> PriceTotalList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < CustomerNames.length; i++) {
        PriceModelList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
        String[] PriceModel = {"s6", "s7", "note4", "note5", "j5", "j6"};
        for (int j = 0; j < PriceModel.length; j++) {
            PriceModelList.get(i).add(PriceModel[j]);
        }

        PriceQtyList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
        String[] PriceQut = {"12", "13", "21", "15", "43", "21"};
        for (int k = 0; k < PriceQut.length; k++) {
            PriceQtyList.get(i).add(PriceQut[k]);
        }

        PriceTotalList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
        String[] PriceTotal = {"1323", "1312321", "43123212", "43434", "12312", "43322"};
        for (int m = 0; m < PriceTotal.length; m++) {
            PriceTotalList.get(i).add(PriceTotal[m]);
        }
    }

    ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> CustomersShoppingLists = new ArrayList<>();
    CustomersShoppingLists.add(PriceModelList);
    CustomersShoppingLists.add(PriceQtyList);
    CustomersShoppingLists.add(PriceTotalList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following works in Java 8..

```
List<String[]> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
```